# Hot deck imputation in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do a hot deck imputation in `R` with the `dplyr` package. I have non-finite values that I would like to replace with a random value drawn from within the same group.

```
myData <- data.frame(value = sample(c(Inf, NaN, 1:8), 100, replace=TRUE), 
                     group = sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE))
  value group
1     4     c
2     6     d
3   Inf     c
4     8     c
5     7     a
6     2     b
```

This code runs but also samples the `Inf` and `NaN` values.

```
myData <- myData %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(imputedvalue = sample(value, n(), replace = TRUE))

table(is.finite(myData$imputedvalue), is.infinite(myData$imputedvalue))

        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE    16    7
  TRUE     77    0
```

This code doesn't run.

```
myData <- myData %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(imputedvalue = ifelse(is.finite(value), value, 
                               sample(value, n(), replace = TRUE)))
Error in n() : This function should not be called directly
```

I feel like there should be a `filter()` command of some sort, but I don't really see how this should work...

Comment: you want `sample(value[is.finite(value)], sum(!is.finite(value)), T)` instead

Comment: @eddi I was thinking along these lines, but when I tried it in `ifelse` I realized that recycling came into play due to the length of the random sample vector differing from the `value` vector.  To guarantee a unique random draw for each non-finite value I had to take a sample the `size` of the group.

Comment: @aosmith you're right, I was thinking more along the lines of assigning to `value[!is.finite(value)]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that involves splitting the dataset up first:

```
# filter non-infinite records

myDataOK <- myData %>%
  filter(value %>% is.finite)

# how many replacements are needed? 
# sample these, a la @eddi

myDataimputed <- myData %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(n_inf = sum(!is.finite(value))) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(sample_n(filter(myDataOK,group == .$group),size = .$n_inf,replace = TRUE))

## and combine!
myData2 <- rbind(myDataOK,myDataimputed)

## here are some various checks:

## same size as original?
nrow(myData2) == nrow(myData)

## all infinites replaced?
with(myData2,table(is.finite(value), is.infinite(value)))

## should be no *decreases* after shuffling.  
## value x block combinations might increase but should never decrease
check1 <- myDataOK %>% 
  group_by(group,value) %>%
  tally %>%
  arrange(group,value)
check2 <- myData2 %>% 
  group_by(group,value) %>%
  tally %>%
  arrange(group,value)
if(any((check2$n-check1$n) < 0)) stop("something went wrong!")


## finally, the increases in group size should equal the number of missing values

Ninf <- myData %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(n_inf = sum(!is.finite(value)))

if(any(tally(check2)$n - tally(check1)$n - Ninf$n_inf !=0) ) 
  stop("group sizes changed!")
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  All I did was correct an error in the OP's code!

Comment: you're replacing all non-finite elements within a group with the **same** value

Comment: Ooh, I like how clean this code is. But for some reason it's slower than the `ifelse` method above...

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald new version changes finite values of `value` and dies for some data; I don't think it does what OP wants

Comment: @eddi changes them how? and also, dies for what kinds of data? I ran it several times and it always works (OP's data is different every time

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald try it on `myData = data.frame(value = c(NA, NA, 1:4), group = 1:2)`; then `set.seed(1234)` and notice how `value == 2` disappears (not to mention the whole scrambling of data problem)

Comment: Also get scrambling here.

Comment: you're both correct! Thank you for saving me.  I updated it *again*, this time including @eddi's approach.  I also added a few checks to make sure that these errors don't happen again ;)